# apache ignite enable rest api how to enable in config file

Tags: rest, ignite

Hi I read the documentation but did not quite understand how to enable the REST API, according to the documentation, you need to copy ignite-rest-http from IGNITE_HOME/libs/optional/ in IGNITE_HOME/libs, I did as written, that is, I copied ignite-rest-http from /usr/lib/apache-ignite/optional to: /usr/lib/apache-ignite, but I do not understand how to write it correctly in the xml file. After reading through the forums I did not find a solution unfortunately. Since I am not an expert on apache ignite please tell me how to solve this problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After starting Ignite node it should automatically bind port `8080`, no configuration is required. You may configure Jetty settings using [`ConnectorConfiguration`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ConnectorConfiguration.html#setJettyPath-java.lang.String-).

I can see that you are using RPM or DEB package. I tried doing that, and it seems to work as advertised, sans the requirement of actually needing to move/symlink directories under /usr/lib:

```
/usr/lib/apache-ignite% ls -dal /usr/lib/apache-ignite/ignite-rest-http                                                                                                                13:41
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 апр  8 13:20 /usr/lib/apache-ignite/ignite-rest-http

>>> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 2.10.0#20210310-sha1:bc24f6baf3e9b4f98cf98cc5df67fb5deb5ceb6c
>>> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> OS name: Linux 5.4.0-70-generic amd64
>>> CPU(s): 4
>>> Heap: 7.8GB
>>> VM name: 66117@ikasnacheev-ThinkPad-P51s
>>> Local node [ID=30D37856-58DD-4935-A013-E9D83986264B, order=1, clientMode=false]
>>> Local node addresses: [192.168.1.104/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1, /192.168.1.104]
>>> Local ports: TCP:8080 TCP:10800 TCP:11211 TCP:47100 UDP:47400 TCP:47500
```

Did you restart the service after the fact?

Comment: I checked the open ports on the node, but not a single service listens to port 8080, I use my own XML configuration file and I run systemctl start apache-ignite@test1.xml does this not affect the REST API ? [links screenshot] (https://disk.yandex.ru/d/4EgBNAVNuhgaBQ)

Comment: Thank you for helping it all work curl http://172.31.XX.XXX:8080/ignite?cmd=version
{"successStatus":0,"sessionToken":null,"error":null,"response":"2.9.1"}